# Ignore pam_authz_search for a specific service

Tags: ldap, pam

It is possible to use pam_authz_search option in libpam-ldapd nslcd config file to filter authentication attempts based on a custom pattern.

Is it possible to make specific service to be exempt from this filtering while authenticating?

Comment: you should be able to use an ldap filter according to https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM (see allow logins on a per group basis).

Comment: @natxoasenjo I'm well aware of the page you linked. How could it help answering my question?

Comment: as you did not indicate what you had done, and you asked if it's possible, then my answer is quite reasonable. If you had wanted another answer they you should have probably asked a different question ;-)

Comment: @natxoasenjo Please elaborate on how the link you provided answers the possibility of overriding pam_authz_search for a specific service

Comment: use an ldap filter. Maybe if you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve, then you will get more elaborate answers.

Comment: I do use a ldap filter already, but I need a way to "Ignore pam_authz_search for a specific service". I'm quoting the question title btw ;)

Comment: use the pam configuration for all services but the one you want to exclude?

Comment: use specific nslcd configuration with pam_authz_search, but overriding this particular filter for a specific service